# Why my reverse array function's output is as same as input?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a reverse array function and I met the problem. The compiler said my input and my output is the same.

Why did this happen?

Requirement:

Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.

Example1:

> Input: `["h","e","l","l","o"]`
>   Output: `["o","l","l","e","h"]`

Example2:

> Input: `["H","a","n","n","a","h"]`
>   Output: `["h","a","n","n","a","H"]`

Here is my JS:

```js
  var reverseString = function(str) {
    var nowArray = [];
    nowArray.push(str);
    var newArray = [];
    for(let i=nowArray.length-1, k=0; i>=0; i--, k++) {
      newArray[k] = nowArray[nowArray.length-1];
      nowArray.length--;
    }
    console.log(newArray);
  };

reverseString( ["h","e","l","l","o"]) // Should return["o","l","l","e","h"]
```

Comment: I know it's not the question, but to reverse a string: `str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Comment: @Kaiido i tried but the leetcode said str.split is not defined

Comment: Because you are not reversing a string, but an Array. And Arrays have built-in `reverse` method. So your function really should be `reverseArray = function(arr) { return arr.slice().reverse(); }`, my first comment was for a String.

Comment: That's because ```.split()``` is for strings. The ```str``` variable is an array.

Comment: @Kaiido OK...maybe i should changed the question's content

Comment: You should modify your post to better reflect the requirements, because you need to modify the original variable. The leetcode question specifically tells you not to use another array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55175230/10576634

Comment: Sorry,guys. I didn't look at the description in the leetcode.Now i understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You donot need to `push()` `str` in `nowArray`. This will make it like this

```
[["h","e","l","l","o"]]
```

You can directly set it to `nowArray`

```js
var reverseString = function(str){
  var nowArray=str;
  
  var newArray=[];
  for(let i=nowArray.length-1,k=0;i>=0;i--,k++){
     newArray[k]=nowArray[nowArray.length-1];
     nowArray.length--;
  }
  console.log(newArray);
  };
  reverseString( ["h","e","l","l","o"])//Should return["o","l","l","e","h"]
```

Use the following in leetcode

```
var reverseString = function(s) {
    for(let i = 0;i<Math.floor(s.length/2);i++){
        let temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[s.length - 1 - i]
        s[s.length - 1 - i] = temp;

    }
};
```

Comment: Wait,i run your code in leetcode.It's ouput is [].Why?

Comment: @Jacky give link to that. I can check it

Comment: Leetcode wants you to modify the str variable that you are originally passed. This copies the data into a new array.

Comment: @Jacky I added a solution for leetcode which is cleaner and working

Comment: @Jacky Because leetcode wants to change the variable `s` instead of creating own variables so you just need to loop through half of array and swap elements corresponding to them

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing the entire string to the `nowArray` instead of the individual characters. Instead just do `var nowArray = str.split("")` to get an array of characters.

```js
var reverseString = function(str) {
  var nowArray = str.split("");
  var newArray = [];
  for (let i = nowArray.length - 1, k = 0; i >= 0; i--, k++) {
    newArray[k] = nowArray[nowArray.length - 1];
    nowArray.length--;
  }
  console.log(newArray);
};
reverseString("hello");
```

Also, you were passing an array of characters instead of a string to the `reverseString` function.

---

Additionally, since you're splitting the string into the `nowArray`, you can eliminate the second array, and just use that one. This also lets you cut the iterations in half.

```js
var reverseString = function(str) {
  var nowArray = str.split("");
  for (let i = nowArray.length - 1, k = 0; i > k; i--, k++) {
    [nowArray[i], nowArray[k]] = [nowArray[k], nowArray[i]];
  }
  console.log(nowArray);
};
reverseString("hello");
```

Comment: If you see his question carefully he is passing array of characters and not string. You can change your answer accordingly.

Comment: @RahulRaut: I noted that in my answer. Since the questions explains that he wants to create a reverse string function, that input to the function would seem to be a mistake, otherwise it's actually a "reverse array" function.

Comment: Simply ask him that by commenting on his question, instead of assuming. :)

Comment: Aren't we both assuming? :)

Comment: In his question he had already passed array of characters as input. :)

Comment: @RahulRaut: Yep, but in the same question, he already referred to it as a string reverse function and even named the parameter `str`. :)

Comment: @RahulRaut: Also, look at what OP describes as the output. It isn't what is encountered when the code actually runs, which returns an array in an array. Pretty sure the input in the demo is mistaken instead of everything else in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need the answer as an array, hence the forced string to array.
You could make the code simpler:

```
var reverseString = function(str){
  var newStr = [];
  for(var i in str) {
    newStr.unshift(str[i]);
  }
  return newStr;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacky, you can also modify the array in place without taking up additional memory. This takes the original string and swaps the values of the two endpoints. Make sure that you quit the loop at `str.length/2` otherwise you will get the exact same array. Furthermore, since you are changing the original input, you do not need to return anything since js passes the arguments by reference.

```js
var reverseString = function(str){
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length/2; i++){
     // you can swap like this ES6
     [str[i],str[str.length-i-1]] = [str[str.length-i-1],str[i]];
     // or like this
     //var tmp = str[i];
     //str[i] = str[str.length-i-1]];
     //str[str.length-i-1]] = tmp;
  }
  console.log(str);
  };
  reverseString( ["h","e","l","l","o"])//Should return["o","l","l","e","h"]
```